# Can't get Twitter User Profile data in Python

Tags: python, twitter, oauth

I want to get the user profile data authenticated Twitter. Actually, `access_token` can get fetched but the error occurs when the application would get `twitter_profile_detail`.

error code:

```
response 410
```

My code:

```py
    access_token_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token'
    protected_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/account/settings.json'

    oauth_token = request.args.get('oauth_token')
    oauth_verifier = request.args.get('oauth_verifier')

    twitter = OAuth1Session(
        client_id,
        client_secret,
        oauth_token,
        oauth_verifier
    )

    response = twitter.post(
        access_token_url,
        params={'oauth_verifier': oauth_verifier}
    )

    access_token = dict(parse_qsl(response.content.decode("utf-8")))

    ## Success fetched

    oauth = OAuth1Session(
        client_id,
        client_secret=client_secret,
        resource_owner_key=access_token["oauth_token"],
        resource_owner_secret=access_token["oauth_token_secret"]
    )

    response = oauth.get(protected_url)

    ## 410 error

    user = get_or_create_user(access_token)
    get_or_create_twitter_profile(user, access_token)
```

Comment: API v1 was shut down in 2012, the correct URL would be `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/settings.json`. can you post the code for your functions `get_or_create_user` and `get_or_create_twitter_profile` as it is impossible to know what these are doing.

Comment: Thanks I got it after replacing url :)

Answer (score 0):

update protected url:

```py
protected_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json'
```